# Parse JSON data within array

Tags: php, json

I have the below JSON and trying to parse it with this foreach.  I only get -104.21 returned.  I am needing the output to be   37.72,-104.21

```
"start_latlng":[
  37.72,
  -104.21
],
```

PHP to loop through "start_latlng" array:   When I `echo` $stLatLng I only get -104.21

```
foreach($stData['start_latlng'] as $latlng) {
   $stLatLng = $latlng;
}
```

Comment: Look into `json_decode`: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `$stLatLng = implode(',', $stData['start_latlng']);`

Comment: If you had JSON, you'd first have to decode it. Where that is done is unclear from your question. Can you replace the first code snippet with the plain PHP code populating `$stData`? You could use `var_export()` to get that, if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that you're getting `-104.21` I presume you are already decoding the JSON into a PHP format.

The reason you'll only be getting that value is because it is the last value in the array, and you're assigning `$stLatLng` to each value of your array as you iterate over it, so the variable will get overwritten each time, see example:

```
foreach($stData['start_latlng'] as $latlng) {
   $stLatLng = $latlng; // first time it's 37.72, second time it's -104.21
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://eval.in/167867) of what's happening in that loop.

---

To get both your values, you don't need to loop it. You can just use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to get both values out [(example)](https://eval.in/167868):

```
list($lat, $lng) = $stData['start_latlng'];
// $lat = 37.72, $lng = -104.21
```